# How to add column which contains query result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table TOUR which has columns arrival_flight and departure_flight and a table FLIGHT which has information about all these flights including dates. I need to add 2 columns arrival_date and departure_date which will be filled automatically proceeded arrival and departure flights dates from.
Can you help me?

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding columns to TOUR and filling the data is possible using triggers on FLIGHT, but messy and fragile. A much cleaner solution would be to create a view on a `SELECT` statement which joins FLIGHT to TOUR once for arrival and once for departure and query that instead of going directly to TOUR.

Comment: How can I do this? I try this

    SELECT  Tour.arrival_flight, Tour.departure_flight FROM Tour
    JOIN Flight ON Flight.num=Tour.arrival_flight OR
    Flight.num=Tour.departure_flight

But it returns 2 lines for one record in TOURS table: one with arrival flight and one for departure

Comment: I like how you rose to the quality of the question. If the op changes to meet so standards, be sure to change accordingly.

Comment: @Leviosa join once for arrival and once for departure, not once for both.